# Setting the default profile in credentials file

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have multiple profiles in my credentials file. How can I get AWS to generate the credentials file with the dev profile as the default?

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id
aws_secret_access_key

[dev]
aws_access_key_id
aws_secret_access_key

[prod]
aws_access_key_id
aws_secret_access_key
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set a named profile as `default` profile in `credentials` file as `default` has special meaning when it comes to profile. However, you set what `profile` to use by default by setting `AWS_PROFILE` environment variable.

it specifies the name of the CLI profile with the credentials and options to use. This can be the name of a profile stored in a credentials or config file, or the value `default` to use the default profile. If you specify this environment variable, it overrides the behavior of using the profile named `[default]` in the configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the same credentials in the `[default]` block that you have in the `[dev]` block:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = KEY_FOR_DEV
aws_secret_access_key = SECRET_FOR_DEV

[dev]
aws_access_key_id = KEY_FOR_DEV
aws_secret_access_key = SECRET_FOR_DEV

[prod]
aws_access_key_id = KEY_FOR_PROD
aws_secret_access_key = SECRET_FOR_PROD
```

etc.

Comment: This credentials file is generated by aws. If I copy the dev profile to default the change will be wiped out when aws replaces this file on the next authentication.

Comment: Then it sounds like you should be using a role and not access keys